# App won't work on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

What settings do I have to change to allow my app to work on iPhone 4? Some people can install it on their iPhone 4's but have problems and others can't.

Is it related to the Required Device Capabilities entry?

[image]

Comment: I guess that would be an operating system problem. Are you sure those working ones and not working one are using the same OS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the general tab for your project check what your deployment target is set to.  If you have it set to iOS 7 then iPhone users running iOS 4,5,6 will not be able to install your app.  Set this to the minimum iOS 7 version you want to support and then you will need to make sure your app works on all those iOS versions for it to run on all iPhone 4s.

Comment: it's set to 6.1 and no one is below 6.1 that has tested it and failed

Comment: Have you tried running your App with iOS 6.1 and 7.0 on iPhone 4?